# Install4j: Wait for a launcher to finish

Tags: install4j

In Install4j, I need to call my application to do initialization within the installer. I use a launcher for that, because it automatically uses the correct JRE and is almost the same as the launcher that will start the application as a service.

I found the 'Execute Launcher' action, but that does not wait after invoking. How can I wait for the launcher to finish?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you have to use the "Run executable or batch file" action and select the "Wait for termination" property.